# Why setTimeout executed only one time?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Function NotifyMe() is performed only one time for a timeout. How to fix?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var mydata = [];
$.ajax({
  url: '3.php',
  async: true, 
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (json) {
    mydata = json.result;
    if ( mydata=="yes" )
    {
        //notifyMe(); 
        setTimeout(notifyMe, 1000);
    }
  }
});
});
```

Comment: How many times do you expect it to be called? `setTimeout` schedules _one_ execution, `setInterval` schedules execution for each tick.

Comment: can  you please print what is the value of mydata using console.log(mydata); inside success ?

Comment: Why do you have a timeout in your ajax success callback in the first place? I'm not sure what you are wanting to happen. The ajax call is only happening once so you wouldn't need to be notified more than once. If you want to keep sending ajax calls, you'd need to put the ajax call in a function passed to setInterval to have it called continuously.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use setInterval instead of setTimeout.

Comment: no setTimeout is correct as he call it again and again in a recursive way

Comment: What is there inside notifyMe ?

Comment: yes ok, sorry i thought it is the same ajax implementation